# Syntax error while parsing model in javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hello all I am Using following syntax in my javascript

```
 var careteam = "@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.CareTeamForFile))";
```

I am getting the following error

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
[Break On This Error]   

var careteam = "[{"GroupId":3,"GroupName":"Physician","Users":[{"UserId":3438,"
```

an arrow  is there indicating position.

I have used this syntax in other places where it works absolutely fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JS you get next line:

```
var careteam = "[{"GroupId":3,"GroupName":"Physician","Users":[{"UserId":3438,"
```

If we will read this line it gives you declaration of variable `var careteam = "[{"`, after you have `GroupId":3,"GroupName":"Physician","Users":[{"UserId":3438,"` which does not make sense for JS.

Change the razor syntax to:

```
var careteam = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.CareTeamForFile))';
```

So in `careteam` you will have a string

```
var careteam = '[{"GroupId":3,"GroupName":"Physician","Users":[{"UserId":3438," ... '
```

But my bet this is not what you want, you want to have an array in `careteam`, so my guess this is the right solution:

```
var careteam = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.CareTeamForFile));
```

And you will get in JS:

```
var careteam = [{"GroupId":3,"GroupName":"Physician","Users":[{"UserId":3438," ...
```

Comment: yea.. outcoldman your first solution works but can u please tell me why it is working in case of                                       var fileforteam = "@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.FileForMyTeam))";

Comment: String in JavaScript can be defined like `var a = 'a';` or `var a = "a";`, no difference, just different syntax. If you need to use `'` or `"` in it you need to escape this symbol by `var a = 'a\'b';` or `var a = "a\"b";`, but you also can change it to `var a = "a'b";` or `var a = 'a"b';`, and you will not need to escape these symbols, because in case where you use `'` you need to escape `'`, but `"` is fine and other way. Hope this is clear :)

Comment: yes fourth one is the correct way with respect of JS and HTML but in razor i am getting `syntax error at ; ` when i declare var careteam = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.CareTeamForFile));

Comment: For the syntax error, change `var careteam = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.CareTeamForFile));` to `var careteam = function () { return @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.CareTeamForFile)); }`